# DISTINCT with UNION and COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in the database to return 6 results in an `Agenda` table that has times available per day  (example: `_08: 10: 00: 000 | 08: 30: 00: 000_`) and periods (example: T (representing `afternoon` or `M` representing `morning`).

I'm getting recover already, but I have a problem I'm not able to resolve.
I can only have a schedule for each period of the day.

Example: On `2015-12-19` I have a time in the morning and a time in the afternoon, but on `2015-12-19` I can never have two hours in the mornings or afternoon.

My query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'M' AS periodo
    FROM AGENDA
    WHERE 
        agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendadata > GETDATE() 
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador, 
        agendadata
    HAVING 
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) AS INT) < 12 
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) A
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'T' AS periodo  
    FROM AGENDA
    WHERE 
        agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendadata > GETDATE()
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador,
        agendadata
    HAVING 
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) AS INT) >= 12 
    AND 
        COUNT(CAST(agendadata AS DATE)) = 1 
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) B
GROUP BY 
    agendaidentificador, 
    agendadata,
    periodo
HAVING 
    COUNT(CAST(agendadata as DATE)) = 1
ORDER BY agendadata
```

The result is:

```
line |agendaIdentificador |             agendaData  | periodo
-----|--------------------|-------------------------|---------
  1  |             173352 | 2015-01-12 12:50:00.000 |   T
  2  |             173363 | 2015-01-12 14:40:00.000 |   T
  3  |             175255 | 2015-01-19 11:30:00.000 |   M
  4  |             175520 | 2015-01-26 14:50:00.000 |   T
  5  |             125074 | 2015-02-25 08:20:00.000 |   M
  6  |             125076 | 2015-02-25 08:40:00.000 |   M
```

Can't happen the same, like lines `1` and `2`.

Comment: Are you getting the top three randomly in your sub-selects?

Comment: Use UNION ALL instead of UNION, because you really want 3 + 3 rows returned. (Less work for server with UNION ALL, since no duplicates have to be eliminated from the result.)

Comment: SpectralGhost yes i'm... 
jarhl I tried with UNION ALL but failed... get duplicates again

Comment: Are you trying to check duplicates against just the Date (without the time) and the period? because your groupby is going against the date AND time.

Comment: cast agentdata in the groupby to a date or strip the time off in a cte or something.

Comment: @KevinCook could you give me a example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @AGENDA TABLE
(
    agendaIdentificador int,
    agendaData  datetime,
    periodo varchar(1),
    agendaconsumolocktempo int,
    agendaconsumoidentificador int

)

INSERT INTO @AGENDA
( agendaIdentificador, agendaData, periodo, agendaconsumolocktempo, agendaconsumoidentificador )
VALUES
(173352, '2015-01-12 12:50:00.000', 'T', null, null),
(173353, '2015-01-12 12:50:00.000', 'T', null, null),
(173354, '2015-01-12 12:50:00.000', 'T', null, null),
(173355, '2015-01-12 12:50:00.000', 'T', null, null),
(173356, '2015-01-13 12:50:00.000', 'T', null, null),
(173363, '2015-01-12 14:40:00.000', 'T', null, null),
(175255, '2015-01-19 11:30:00.000', 'M', null, null),
(175520, '2015-01-26 14:50:00.000', 'T', null, null),
(125074, '2015-02-25 08:20:00.000', 'M', null, null),
(125076, '2015-02-25 08:40:00.000', 'M', null, null),
(125076, '2015-02-25 08:40:00.000', 'M', null, null),
(125076, '2015-02-25 08:40:00.000', 'M', null, null),
(125076, '2015-02-25 08:40:00.000', 'M', null, null),
(125076, '2015-02-26 08:40:00.000', 'M', null, null);
```

Now I fix the test data to split out all of the records for the morning and afternoons and count them.

```
WITH AGENDA AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(agendaData AS DATE), periodo ORDER BY agendaData) RN
    FROM @AGENDA
)
```

Now we take the query from before, but the change for the afternoon session is I only want the first of each set (where RN=1)

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'M' AS periodo
    FROM AGENDA
    WHERE agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND agendadata > GETDATE() 
    AND DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) < 12
    AND RN = 1
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador, 
        agendadata
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) A
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'T' AS periodo  
    FROM AGENDA
    WHERE agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND agendadata > GETDATE()
    and RN = 1
    and DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) >= 12
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador,
        agendadata
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) B
GROUP BY 
    agendaidentificador, 
    agendadata,
    periodo
ORDER BY agendadata
```

here is the output:

```
agendaidentificador agendadata  periodo
173352  2015-01-12 12:50:00.000 T
173356  2015-01-13 12:50:00.000 T
175255  2015-01-19 11:30:00.000 M
175520  2015-01-26 14:50:00.000 T
125074  2015-02-25 08:20:00.000 M
125076  2015-02-26 08:40:00.000 M
```

I added some more duplicate records, cleaned up all of the useless having clauses

Comment: You really don't need the having clauses, I didn't fix the rest of your query.  From your explanation, I guess you allow multiple records for the morning, but only 1 afternoon appointment?  If it is only one for each period of the day, then just use RN=1 on both sides of the union.

Comment: I try again and found duplicates again =/ and other... afternoon can return more than 1 appointment, but not to same date

Comment: I added several duplicates, cleaned up the code, fixed both sides of the equation, I do not get duplicates with this code.  Were you getting duplicates on the morning side with the old code? (that was left that way, now it is set as you stated in your last comment)

Comment: Based on your answer, I create a second AGENDA2 to get afternoon apointment... When i was following your way I got unique but always got appointment to 12:00 PM

Comment: you are using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(agendaData AS DATE), periodo ORDER BY agendaData) RN?  is periodo a part of your partition?

Comment: is a virtual column, just used to other feature but not in PARTITION, I remove from partition and work too

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by (the final group by) only by the datepart of "AgendaData". U cant group by the whole date + time field.

i Think this should work : group by TO_CHAR("timestamp_field",'YYYY-MM-DD')

Answer (score -1):

Based on @Kevin Cook answer, I just added other `CTE` and this solved my problem.

```
WITH CTE_AGENDA AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(agendaData AS DATE) ORDER BY newid(),agendaData) RN
    FROM AGENDA
)
,CTE_AGENDA2 AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(agendaData AS DATE) ORDER BY newid(),agendaData desc) RN2
    FROM AGENDA
)

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'M' AS periodo
    FROM AGENDA
    WHERE 
        agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendadata > GETDATE() 
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador, 
        agendadata
    HAVING 
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) AS INT) < 12 
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) A
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'T' AS periodo  
    FROM AGENDA2
    WHERE     
        agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendadata > GETDATE()
        and RN2 = 1
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador,
        agendadata
    HAVING 
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) AS INT) >= 12 
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) B
GROUP BY 
    agendaidentificador, 
    agendadata,
    periodo
HAVING 
    COUNT(CAST(agendadata as DATE)) = 1
ORDER BY agendadata,periodo
```

Comment: `COUNT(CAST(agendadata as DATE)) = 1` Why do you need the `CAST`?